# How to show recipes from Private Repository in AppCatlog WEBUI for Cloudify V2.7

Tags: cloudify

How can we show the Private Repo Recipes in AppCatlog WebUI for Cloudify V2.7.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the Cloudify application catalog has been tested only with public repositories.
However, it should work with private repositories as well, as long as the repo's url contains the username and password. - But (again) it has never been tested.
More info about the application catalog can be found [here](http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/setup/recipes_tab.html).

HTH,
Tamir.